# Echad Va-arba'im Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred forty one?

### אחד וארבעים ושלוש מאות - מי יודע?‏

The traditional Passover song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea) implies a possible presupposition that there is a Jewish significance to be found for each [natural number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number). Accordingly, there is an [ongoing series](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) on Mi Yodeya that is attempting to unearth significant Judaism facts about each number, in sequence.

What significant Judaism facts are there about the number 341? The more significant within Judaism and the more intrinsically dependent on the value 341, the stronger the answer. Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Maybe lazy gematria is a good thing, or maybe you should stay away from it like you do from fire, knowing that if your answer last night was lazy gematria, your burden today and into the future will be guilt. Please don't base your answer on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Sefer Ezra, when the Jewish nation returned to Eretz Yisrael for the second Bais HaMikdash, 4289 Kohanim returned ([2:36-39](http://www.sefaria.org/Ezra.2.36-39?lang=bi)), while only 341 Leviyim returned ([2:40-42](http://www.sefaria.org/Ezra.2.40-42?lang=bi)).

Hat-tip: [Sefer  ראיות מכריעות נגד ולהויזן - הופמן, דוד צבי בן משה](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38205&st=&pgnum=90&hilite=).

Comment: +1 I'm not sure the Kohanim data is helpful here. There are plenty of numbers in that list. We're only interested in the "341".

Comment: @DoubleAA the contrast is worthy of note. I find that answers in this series are most compelling if they offer some contextual meat on the numerical bone.

Answer (score 2):

341 are the fewest days in a year without Kiddush Levana, assuming one is able to say Kiddush Levana once per month, as prescribed. The shortest year has 353 days and 12 months.

Comment: "assuming one is able to say Kiddush Levana once per month, as prescribed": actually, it's the fewest days in a year without _kidush l'vana_, period. You don't need to assume that.

Comment: msh210 You should ping the author of that phrase, @isaacmoses

Answer (score -1):

Lazy gematrios: מקרא, פרה אדומה, מגן אברהם and of course המלפפונים

Comment: The question has been edited to preclude gematriyot, so this is no longer an answer.